# Top active users in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to learn basic Linux so I'm doing a bit of extra homework.
I need to write a shell script that displays in real time the top x users by number of active processes with a delay of n seconds (where x and n are command line parameters).

I pretty much know how to do this, except the core part of it: How can I find who are the top users by number of active processes?

I fooled around with top command, but that did not got me where I want to be.

Comment: Hi, stick up what you've written so far and friendly SO peeps will give you pointers.  You'll need to put up the code you've written and what it's doing\not doing.

Comment: ps ax -o user | sort | uniq -c

Comment: @BanksySan I did a really simple shell script that takes 3 parameters from the command line and displays the first $1 lines from $3 file in an infinite loop with a delay of $2 seconds (I need to add some validation to this to be sure that I don't attempt to print 'abc' lines from a file that does not exist).

Comment: Now I try to take @William Pursell's command step by step to understand it. Then I'll try to adapt that old script to display the first lines from this command.

Comment: you know about the `man` utility? I.e. `man ps`, `man sort`, `man uniq`? You should be all set then. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter I know :) that's what I was trying to say by taking it step by step. man ps, look around, try something :) I have it working now. Tomorrow I'll try to make it more efficient and more easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on William's post above,

head -5 to show the top 5.

sleep 10 to sleep 10 sec between re-checks.

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to check that you get two arguments and use $1 and $2 in the right places.

```
while [ 1 ]
do
   date
   ps ax -o user | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5
   sleep 10
done
```